# Exchange 2010 EWS: Retrieve the Starred status of a message using XML?

Tags: soap, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I'm constrained to using XML soap requests to get and set the starred status of messages using Exchange 2010 EWS.

How can I get the "Starred" or "Favourite" status of a message? Setting it would be nice too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will return the starred status of a message using XML for EWS 2010:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>
        <t:IncludeMimeContent>true</t:IncludeMimeContent>
        <t:AdditionalProperties>
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" />
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="0x1090" PropertyType="Integer"/>
        </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </ItemShape>
      <ItemIds>
        <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADg5MmFjNTViLTYwODUtNGNmYi04MzhjLTczZTdkOTZmYjllNwBGAAAAAABFQx5qtI0+R7P3jIlj8lBrBwCGvs35WFEvTaNeDfAlU93XAAAAFfBdAACGvs35WFEvTaNeDfAlU93XAAAAF4LGAAA=" ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAACGvs35WFEvTaNeDfAlU93XAAAAF+bq"/>
      </ItemIds>
    </GetItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```